# Disappeared panel with Preview in AS

Tags: android, gradle

The panel on the right with the following tabs(`Preview`, `Gradle`) disappeared, after i update: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

Comment: There will be gradle error due to which sync failed and you're not having that both tabs, I'm using 3.2.1 version also not having such issue.

Comment: @JeelVankhede how can I display these tabs?

Comment: Go to **View->Tool Windows-> Gradle**, it'll open consequent tab.

Answer (score 0):

I just go in **View -> Tool Buttons**

Menu displayed